# Dismatching dimensions when trying to adjust the width and height

Tags: photoshop

I haven't got the right dimensions for my picture when i try to adjust the width and height, nder the `image menu->image size`, i try to give dimensions to my picture of 640 as width and 960 as height, however, i couldn't do that, here is what i got :

[image]

I try to export my picture as  PNG, but the dimensions are automatically given when just adjust either the height or the width, so i didn't got the right one that i need.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unclick the 'Conserver les proportions' checkbox, that will let you specify height and width without Photoshop doing any automatic scaling

Comment: Whoever downvoted this would you care to explain what's wrong with the answer? Or are you just trolling?

Comment: I already did comment on the question!

Comment: So why did you downvote this answer to the question? The answer is correct after all

Comment: thanx Clive, you really helped me :)